# How to authenticate user credentials by back end using Oauth2 in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, oauth-2.0, xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin and now I am facing the issue how to authenticate the user by my back end system. Building my app in de xamarin forms, already created the login page where the user can fill in the credentials (name and password)

What I found so far, is some libraries in nuGet (xamarin.Auth and clancey.simpleAuth) to bad there isn't a good documentation hoe to use those libraries with a custom server.

my code:

```
        LoginButton.Clicked += async (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                var api = new OAuthPasswordApi(
                    "google",
                    App.ClientId,
                    App.ClientSecret,
                    App.RedirectUrl,
                    App.AccessTokenUrl,
                    App.AuthorizeUrl
                )
                { ScopesRequired = false };

                var account = await api.Authenticate();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

            }
        };
```

The code now throws a nullReferenceException in the Authenticate function.

```
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3539/f37444ae/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 at SimpleAuth.AuthenticatedApi+<Authenticate>d__15.MoveNext () [0x000c1] in <filename unknown>:0
```

My back end for authenticating is a symfony2 web application using FOS restBundle.

Does anyone have some tips or documentation on how it should be implemented?

Comment: If you are a asp.net kind-of-person:  http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server

Comment: I've used `node-oauth2-server` a few times... https://github.com/oauthjs/node-oauth2-server

Comment: thanks, will give it a look